# Same hardware cluster

Tags: hardware, cluster-computing, google-cloud-sql

If I have two databases and views in one in which both databases are JOIN'ed or UNION'ed is this an issue for for GCSql? This feature according to MySQL only requires that both databases remain within the same hardware cluster.

I am not totally clear on what constitutes a hardware cluster, but how does that relate to google SQL instances, etc?

Comment: If you can do something like `select table.field, othertable.otherfield FROM db1.table, db2.othertable` then you should be ok. If the dbs are are in totally different mysql instances, then you'd need to look at using a federated table to make one of the "remote/foreign" tables appear as local in one of the mysql servers.

Comment: OK for now they are both in the same instance and everything (other settings I am not yet familiar with).

Comment: clustering servers for all intents and purposes turns multiple "small" servers into a "single" large server. you don't have worry about which of the smaller member servers is actually handling/executing your requests - the clustering software takes care of all those details. but you can always run multiple independent copies of mysql, and each of those would have no knowledge of any database defined in the other instances. that's when you couldn't directly select from multi-hosted databases

Comment: "but you can always run multiple independent copies of mysql, and each of those would have no knowledge of any database defined in the other instances." -- that is what I was thinking -- thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Google Cloud SQL instances has a single MySQL instance at any one time. The data is replicated to multiple locations when that single MySQL instance writes it to persistent storage -- this means that the instance can failover to a new location if there is a problem.

There isn't any hardware clustering in the sense used here.

Comment: Excellent thank you...so I should have no issues querying from two databases in the same instance?